# executing hotkeys from a script into an application

Tags: shell-script, desktop-environment, keyboard-event

Is it possible to open an application, then execute some hotkeys associated with that application using a script? For example if I wanted to open Firefox (using Firefox & for example)then I wanted to go to the Downloads tab using Ctrl + J.

Comment: how about you tell firefox to open the download tab instead? Trying to emulate a keyboard to do that is one way, but seems to be a bit convoluted, unless you really want to do more keyboard-centric stuff.

Comment: so, is that firefox example just that – an example – or what's the end goal here? Many software can be *scripted*, so that you don't have to go through emulating keyboard shortcuts, but not all. In the case of firefox, there's the `--marionette` option and `geckodriver` for a lot of things, or you could write a Javascript extension, or there's probably existing macro recorders!

Comment: @MarcusMüller , what do you mean by "telling firefox"? I am a bit confused.  I was also just using it as a example for simplicity, my actual goal involves opening a certain application, have it open files, have the user verify the validity of the files then return control back to the command line utility wherein it will execute that same process again  until the required files have been checked.

Comment: What I meant is that you can "puppeteer" many modern applications, like Firefox, gimp, libreoffice, emacs, ... by using their native scripting support, instead of faking keypresses. Your script could directly tell the application to do something, rather than faking the key press to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plethora of tools for this purpose, in all modern languages, like Python, Javascript, for testing and automation.

A native Linux way to do this is [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool), which is using X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.
So it is expected to work with Gnome, KDE, Xfce4 and similar desktop environments, but not with Wayland.

A simple example to send a key to open the Downloads window for your Firefox window (modifying the README page example):

```
xdotool search "Mozilla Firefox" windowactivate --sync key --clearmodifiers ctrl+Y
```

After installing it, `man xdotool` to see available actions.

Note: It's available for macos also, as you use Ctrl+J to open Downloads Window.